# jQuery validate - prevent the error label being displayed

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I am using the jQuery validate plugin for doing 'live' form validation. I am trying to not show the error messages that appear as it affects the layout etc..

It generates a label that messes up my styling on the page, is it possible to have this not display at all?

```
// the label it generates for an error
<label for="address_1" class="error">Please enter at least 2 characters.</label> 

$('#checkout-form').validate({
    rules: {
        first_name: {
            minlength: 2,
            required: true
        },
        last_name: {
            minlength: 2,
            required: true
        }
    },
    highlight: function (element) {
        $(element).addClass('#error')
          .closest('.form-group').removeClass('valid');
    },
    success: function (element) {
        element.addClass('valid')
          .closest('.form-group').removeClass('error');
    }
});

// custom css
<style type="text/css">
label.valid {
position: relative;
top: -25px;
right: 10px;
float: right;
width: 16px;
height: 16px;
background: url('/assets/images/icons/tick.png') center center no-repeat;
display: inline-block;
text-indent: -9999px;
}

label.nonvalid {
position: relative;
top: -25px;
right: 10px;
float: right;
width: 16px;
height: 16px;
background: url('/assets/images/icons/cross.png') center center no-repeat;
display: inline-block;
text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `showErrors` parameter to contain your own logic to show messages as you need them:

```
$('#checkout-form').validate({
    showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
        // do something with the errors
    },
    // rest of your code...
});
```

Comment: I've added some CSS code - can anyone suggest how to get the error to show the .nonvalid class when an error & when no error show the .valid class

Answer (score 1):

You can use `errorPlacement` like,

```
$('#checkout-form').validate({
    errorClass:'error_border',
    rules: {
        first_name: {
            minlength: 2,
            required: true
        },
        last_name: {
            minlength: 2,
            required: true
        }
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element){
      /* Need to add this function to remove the error default placement */
    }
});
```

Read [Error handling in jQuery Validation Plugin](http://www.kianworknotes.com/2013/06/error-handling-in-jquery-validation.html)